# How do I make a single letter in a string uppercase

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to take an input text file and make every "i" that is by itself uppercase. This is my code so far, but it creates one long line of code instead of keeping the line breaks and paragraphs.

```
with open("greenEggsAndHam.txt", "r") as myfile:
    iText = myfile.read().split()

oText = ''

for word in iText:
    if(word == "i"):
        word = word.upper()
    oText = oText + word + " "
print oText
```

the output is now like this:

```
I am Sam Sam I am That Sam-i-am!That Sam-i-am! I do not like that Sam-i-am!
```

instead of this:

```
I am Sam
Sam I am

That Sam-i-am!
That Sam-i-am!
I do not like that Sam-i-am!
```

is there a way to do this while keeping paragraphs and line breaks?

Comment: The indentation in your question is a bit off. Anyway, have you thought of `readline`? The hard returns disappear because you split, and you never insert them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code fails as you split the text into one large list of individual words so any newlines are removed, that is why you are left with one large line of text.

You can split each line as you iterate over the file object and check for `i`:

```
with open("greenEggsAndHam.txt", "r") as myfile:
   for line in myfile:
       print(" ".join([w.upper() if w == "i" else w for w in line.split()]))
```

If you want one large body of text:

```
with open("greenEggsAndHam.txt", "r") as myfile:
   text = "\n".join([" ".join([ch.upper() if ch == "i" else ch for ch in line.split()]) for line in myfi
```

Comment: @torogitar:  For details, see the third paragraph of the [`split` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split): "If _sep_ is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is applied...".

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
string = re.sub('\bi\b', 'I', string)
```

Comment: This won't work because `-` is a non-word character, so `-i-` is at a word boundary.

Comment: It will create `Sam-I-am` instead of `Sam-i-am`.